# How can I get a list of the biggest packages currently installed in order?

Tags: dpkg

I am running out of disk space on my root partition, and I'm attempting to remove some packages and not others.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend just to remove the most bigger packages but the less used ones.

Comment: like @Braiam said.. You should rather remove the less used ones and the older kernel images among others. You could also remove _(maybe backup them first, in case you want them for offline installations later)_ the .deb files in the `/var/cache/apt/archives` using `sudo apt-get clean` in the terminal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First install *debian-goodies* by running the below command,

```
sudo apt-get install debian-goodies
```

Then run the below command to view the installed packages which has large size,

```
dpigs -H
```

By default,it was set to display installed 10 largest packages.You can set the number by `-n` parameter.

```
dpigs -n 20 -H
```

The above command lists installed largest 20 packages.

```
$ dpigs -h

Usage: dpigs [options]

Options:
  -n, --lines=N
    Display the N largest packages on the system (default 10).
  -s, --status=status-file
    Use status-file instead of the default dpkg status file.
  -S, --source
    Display the largest source packages of binary packages installed
    on the system.
  -H, --human-readable
    Display package sizes in human-readable format (like ls -lh or du -h)
  -h, --help
    Display this message.
```

Comment: In order to get this command, at least in 13.10, you need to install `debian-goodies` via the `sudo apt-get install debian-goodies` command.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Synaptic Package Manager install it by typing the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

*(But first make sure you have allowed the Universe repository. Here's a link for the how-to: [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository))*

Next, start Synaptic Package Manager (reload the repos if necessary) and click on the <kbd>**Status**</kbd> tab, then click ***Installed***,

[image: snap1]

From *Settings* menu, select *Preferences*,

[image: snap2]

Click <kbd>Column and Fonts</kbd> tab, scroll to find **Installed Size** and mark it, then click <kbd>**OK**</kbd>,

[image: snap3]

Now the **Size** column should appear in the Synaptic window. Click on *Size* to select sort column by size and toggle for ascending/descending order of arrangement.

[image: snap4]

You can then select the packages you want to remove and apply the action from this application itself.