# Find package that use the most disk space

Tags: apt, package-management

In my university exam I had this question:
*Find Debian package that use the most disk space.*

My teammate solved this question with the following solution:

```
apt show ".*" | grep "Download-Size:" | cut -f2 -d" " | sort -nrk 1 | head -n 1
```

But I had to use "Installed-Size" because the Unit Size of Download-Size and Installed-Size is different for each package as it depends on its size and also does not identify which package the size is referring to.

Is it possible to solve this question using APT ?

Comment: `sort` supports the "human-readable" units if you use `-h` instead of `-n`.

Comment: @muru Example please

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/406155/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-biggest-packages-currently-installed-in-order